# ActiveAdmin New and Edit With has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Everything works fine in development but in production it breaks in new and edit action. Here is the production log:

```
.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-5a2b7b5bc683/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb (191.9ms)
I, [2015-07-31T10:51:31.326590 #26202]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 254ms
F, [2015-07-31T10:51:31.329305 #26202] FATAL -- : 
ActionView::Template::Error (too many arguments for format string):
    1: insert_tag renderer_for(:new)
  app/admin/business.rb:51:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  app/admin/business.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My Business Model:

```
has_many :business_attributes, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :business_attributes, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
```

My BusinessAttribute Model:

```
belongs_to :business
```

ActiveAdmin:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Business do
 form(allow_destroy: true, html: { multipart: true }) do |f|
  ...other_fields..
  f.has_many :business_attributes do |attribute|
    attribute.input :name
    attribute.input :value
  end
 f.actions
 end
 permit_params :param, :param, ....
end
```

I am using activeadmin '1.0.0.pre1' with rails 4.2.0 my production stack is nginx and unicorn if that helps. Any comment and reply is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I could not fix the activeadmin issue. But I found a workaround the problem(it was unable to build the form from the relation).

```
form partial: 'form'
```

Rendering a form partial fixed the issue. I used coocon gem for nested attributes.

Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you can use a stable version of activeadmin as recommended

you can try this

```
form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
```

and also put

```
f.has_many :business_attributes do |attribute|
   attribute.input :_destroy, :as => boolean
   attribute.input :name
   attribute.input :value
```

As your model already has

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :business_attributes, allow_destroy: true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that did not work. Same error :(

Comment: activeadmin stable version?

Comment: Sadly there is no stable version for rails 4.2 yet

Comment: please usegithub one `gem 'activeadmin', git: 'https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git'`

Comment: Same issue with the github master branch.